# Вывод данных или привязка имен к связанным спискам php формы , ajax

Tags: php, ajax, формы

Ребята есть вот такой код

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <table>
<tr>
<td>Страна: </td>
<td><select id="dhtmlgoodies_country" name="dhtmlgoodies_country" onchange="getCityList(this)">
<option value="">Выберите страну</option>
<option value="ru">Россия</option>
<option value="ua">Украина</option>
<option value="us">США</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Город: </td>
<td><select id="dhtmlgoodies_city" name="dhtmlgoodies_city">

</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Привязка библиотек

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="chained.js"></script>
```

файл из которого берутся города

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['countryCode'])){

      switch($_GET['countryCode']){

      case "ru":
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Москва','1');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Санкт-Петербург','2');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Волгоград','3');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Владивосток','4');\n";


      break;
      case "ua":

      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Киев','11');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Одесса','12');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Львов','13');\n";

      break;
      case "us":

      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Нью-Йорк','21');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Чикаго','22');\n";
      echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Вашингтон','23');\n";

      break;
      } 
      }    
?>
```

Как сделать значение name = '' для каждого города ? мне в последующем нужно для обработки в другом скрипте данных , у меня учитывается и страна , но на неё можно в первом коде прикрепить наименования, а вот на города не пойму...

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста , или как сделать связанный список , с дальнейшей пост обработкой данных , мне для запроса в базу данных ((

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы в `select`  -> `option` был аттрибут `name` = "Название города" ?

Comment: Да , именно так , мне нужен связанный список ..  что б лишнего не было поле , и что б к каждому городу была привязка атрибута `name`="значение"